# Wine won't start, lxtask shows absurdly large VM-Size associated with it

Tags: wine, lubuntu

I'm running Wine on Lubuntu 14.04 and everything worked fine until today when I tried to start a Windows program and it wouldn't run. After having the same result with several other programs I tried to open wine config, but the same thing happened.

I've tried to kill all the processes associated with Wine and tried again, but the same thing happened. After restarting (because maybe I didn't close all of them), same thing.

When I've looked more carefully under lxtask, it showed WM-Size of 16777216,0 TB for anything related to Wine.

I've tried reinstalling the Wine, but it looks like I've done something wrong because:

1. The problem persists.
2. Somehow, now the wine config is lost from the menu.

Last time Wine worked was when I was when I've set it to behave like Win98.

Comment: Does it also happen in different Wine prefixes? Try `export WINEPREFIX=/tmp/wine; winecfg`.

Comment: It seems that the procedure described on http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#uninstall worked.